# Couchbase N1ql query fetch eagerly in Java

Tags: java, spring, couchbase

I have a Java Couchbase n1ql query like this:

```
N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(sql), queryTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Unfortunately, in some cases this query can return a lot of rows and then need to be iterated over. This is taking a long time as it appears the docs are being fetched lazily. I would like to implement eagerly fetching the docs, which I gather means setting `includeDocs` to true.

How can I set the query to fetch eagerly or set the get batch size to a high number?

Comment: What you mean by being fetched lazily? How did you make this conclusion?

Comment: @deniswsrosa - It is taking hours to go through the list. I'm not 100% sure this is the cause but pretty certain. I am however 100% sure I can't figure out how to set the fetch size or the param to load the results eagerly like I could in other JPA frameworks. If I could do that then I could be 100% sure.

Comment: I would recommend you to try the reactive API if possible, so even if you have a lot of results, the documents will be streamed as they arrive. But I doubt that couchbase has  Lazy/Eager configuration. After all, it is a document database, so there is no extra cost on bringing the whole document other than the size of the response itseld.

Comment: @deniswsrosa - You may be right, I just can't find anything definitive one way or the other. I do know that `ViewQuery` has a method called includeDocs which forces eager instantiation. Maybe that concept doesn't extend to queries, since like you say, there is no time penalty for eager loading.

Comment: The `includeDocs` does not apply to a N1qlQuery.  There can actually be an extra cost, because in this case it depends on how the query engine satisfies the request.  If it can be done from a covered index, then no KV fetch is needed by the query engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bisect the performance, you can try changing the sql to select only the meta().id.  Also, check the explain for the query in the console, see if it's using an index other than the primary index.

In this case, there is not a batch size or eager fetch.  All of that detail is handled by the query engine.  The SDK sends the request, and the query engine streams results.  There is a streaming parser in the SDK to process the rows that come in, but that usually is not the dominator.

Another thing you can do is check the metrics returned.  Comparison of the time observed on the client and what is recorded used at the query engine would be good.  See the [N1qlMetrics](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.7.0/com/couchbase/client/java/query/N1qlQueryResult.html#info--) or the [profileInfo()](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.7.0/com/couchbase/client/java/query/N1qlQueryResult.html#profileInfo--) (which may need to be enabled on the query).